# Why the horrendous sci-fi sound after the T-1000 is hit with a slug and then tumbles into the molten steel?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

Towards the end of Terminator Judgement Day, the T-1000 emits a horrendous screech, as it tries to recover from the exploded slug and stumbles into the molten steel below it . What would cause it to do this and react in such a way? Did the slug somehow damage some kind of audio mechanism?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYQMfT6nsQs

Comment: @Kyle Jones: A "slug" is another name for a larger bullet right? It makes this sound  after it is hit by the slug and stumbles into the molten steel. It can't thrash off the edge of something. Thrashing means someone or something ran into it. It's the action of doing something to something else, one cannot thrash oneself.

Comment: Slug n. an elongated, typically rounded piece or metal, a bullet, especially one of lead

Comment: The T-1000 was hit by a [grenade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/40_mm_grenade), which under no circumstances is called a slug.

Comment: @Kyle Jones: If you can provide me a screen shot and/or script that insists that he was hit with a grenade, I shall edit the question to fit that. Thanks!

Comment: I know this a bit old, but it is indeed a grenade - administered by an [M79 Grenade Launcher](http://www.imfdb.org/wiki/Terminator_2#M79_grenade_launcher)

Comment: I know this is old, but are you talking about that strange noise it's making _before_ falling into the molten steel? Or the "scream" when it's inside the molten steel?

Answer (score 10):

The Official [T2: Judgement Day](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1153499.Terminator_2) novelisation by Randall Frakes describes the sound thusly:

> The T-1000 took the round directly in the belly. The grenade exploded
>   inside its body. A huge hole drilled clean through it, and ripped the
>   torso open, peeling back, half inside out. Its center of gravity
>   radically shifted, the T-1000 toppled off the edge into the molten
>   steel. John ran up to Sarah and they watched in horror as the thing’s
>   head and upper body reappeared above the molten steel.
>
> **It was screaming. A terrifying, inhuman siren of a scream, as all its
>   molecules were searching for the right channels back into its proper
>   structure, but the intense heat and volubility of the molten metal
>   around it confused them.**

Presumably the screaming is part of the same convulsive response as its (futile) attempt to find a form that will resist the heat.

Comment: I guess it could be justified as another means of dramatic effect. But it is just odd at how, in nearly every other part of the movie, where it is shot, it just quietly recovers and then continues to execute its mission. Of course it is not nearly as badly discombobulated; however, there have been times where the crater goes all the way through its head.  This is the only part it actually cares enough to make a sound that is not really doing anything to help it.

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - It also makes a similar (but less pronounced) sound when shot in the head in the lift scene.

Comment: @Richard- Could you describe to me what that scene was? The lift scene?

Comment: @ArvinGBorkar - My take is that it's trying *everything*, even if it makes no sense. What's it got to lose?

Comment: It's just so unnecessary. I mean, unless it feels pain, it would be totally nonsensical to call for help. Perhaps it wanted John to feel emotion for it to help it back onto the platform so that he could kill him?

Comment: You can see the lift scene at 1:45 : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EYQMfT6nsQs

Comment: This answer makes the most sense. Due to the design of the machine, it has no working parts as such which is why a bullet won't seriously hurt it. It is clearly trying everything to survive at the end, so going through different sounds makes sense. Maybe trying different frequencies if it can shut off a machine or something....nothing left to lose, as you said.

Comment: @SonnyOrdell It's metal striking metal, so that was plausibly a ring / shock absorption.

Comment: "[Volubility](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/volubility)"? Did the author actually write that? (Presumably something like "volatility" was intended.)

Answer (score 3):

The screech is likely an allusion to tin pest/tin crying (and I believe but can't confirm,  one can occur due to the other).

Tin pest is the deformation of tin at low temperatures due to an 'autocatalytic' change in its molecules,  as it goes from metallic to diamond structured. In the case of tin this is due to *low* temperature , but let's afford Cameron poetic license.

Tin crying is the screeching noise let off by tin when it is bent,  or otherwise deformed.

I think this is likely  the inspiration for the noise the T-1000 makes.

Answer (score 1):

You could explain it by the fact its system were failing - we already saw its hands stick to railing and assume the striped colour.  First the freezing and then the rapid thaw before extreme-heat.  Perhaps its higher reasoning was being stripped away and the underlying programming for human-mimicking came to fore - a human like scream when its superior robotic-nature had been largely destroyed.

Comment: Very possible. I would think at some point, hearing audible noises from it, comes with the structure reaching a breaking point. 

As an earlier comment had stated, you could hear a little less pronounced version of this same sound when its head was blown open at the elevator scene.

Comment: I also think there is a bit of what I have heard called 'narrative cueing'.  This weird, horrible scream is VERY, very similar to the noise that 'The Thing' makes in the amazing Johan Carpenter film.  Given the similarities between the creatures and their capabilities I think there was a bit of a nod.  I also perhaps think it might be symbolic of all the people it has murdered and mimicked over the course of the story; all screaming and dying at once - perhaps even more romantically its victims dragging it down to the fires of perdition...  A bit purple that one!!!

Comment: Yeah..why not mimic a noise of individuals dying when it mimics them while taking on their appearances? Good take.

Answer (score 0):

The best explanation I can think of is that the T 1000 is a form of living creature. All creatures scream when they are exposed to enough injury. This is part of the explanation covers the ability to travel through time if we assume it’s alive.

A close examination of the T1k in combat shows it can expertly form and reform itself Except if it’s sustaining weapons fire. The lift scene is great for this. It can form stabbing weapons at will and can fall through holes in the ceiling to then change shape and be combat ready even before it finishes mimicking skin and fabric but it didn’t like concussive force such as bullet impacts at all.

So the head shot in the lift scene stuns its “molecular brain” (check the wiki) and it screams because it has a voice (we hear him talk) but isn’t thinking/processing, it’s just reacting on instinct.

More so, weapons fire shows visible (damage?) areas that the T1k has to stop to reform. In the first fight scene the T1k goes down stunned and motionless until it can reform disrupted areas. So how about 2 modes. 1 be a singular robot that’s on mission. 2. Reform damage/ disrupted areas as a colony of tiny robots that look liquid to the naked eye. We only see splash on the surface but what if the force of the bullet is causing disruption deeper in the T1k body.

So this next part of the explanation is easy. The grenade does concussive disruption to the whole T1k body. It screeches because the brain needs time to reform and can’t think/process just like we cry out in pain when injured. It falls in the molten steel and goes absolutely futilely in a fit of attempting to do anything to survive without being able to think.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Your hypotheses should be backed up by quotes or other citations from original sources - either the movie or an official novelization, or from interviews with the creators - otherwise it's just your personal theory.  Saying that the T1000 is living requires some evidence, since it somewhat contradicts the premise of the movie...

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve ever watched a blacksmith put red hot steel into water or oil it actually screams and creaks.
Look it up on YouTube.

The metal reacts like a tuning fork.

Comment: Instead of saying _"Look it up on YouTube"_ it would be better to include an actual link to a video for evidence.